# Creating plot on ShinyR

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello I'm trying to create shiny app in which I want to display how many orders were In/Out TAT on a graph(Delivered within 24 hrs then In TAT if not then Out TAT).

This is that the Table after dcasting & manipulation the Raw Data I had with me in server.R

```
WareHouse  Order Date   In TAT   Out TAT
W-1        2019-02-14   431      5
W-1        2019-02-15   533      10
W-1        2019-02-16   234      64
W-1        2019-02-17   456      12
W-2        2019-02-14   123      11
W-2        2019-02-15   787      56
W-2        2019-02-16   234      89
W-2        2019-02-17   221      23
W-3        2019-02-14   111      12
W-3        2019-02-15   789      56
W-3        2019-02-16   345      98
W-3        2019-02-17   897      45
```

Now I want to plot a graph in the front page of my shinyapp where I could show how many orders were in TAT and Out of the Different Warehouse at different dates.

Here is what I have achieved as of now.

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(gtools)



shinyUI(

  fluidPage(
    navbarPage(
       title = 'Dashboard',
      tabPanel('Overview'),
       tabsetPanel(
         tabPanel('In/Out TAT Details',
                 fluidRow(
                    # plotlyOutput("overview"),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("view_fwd"),width = 6
                  ) )
         ),
       tabPanel('B2C Details'  
       ))))
```

In Server.R I'm reading the file and calculating the TAT of the orders & creating the table a shown above

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)



shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

overview <- reactive({  
  library(DT)
  library(RPostgreSQL)
  library(markdown)
  library(dplyr)
  library(reshape2)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(plotly)

  m <- read.csv("/data/xia2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
  x <- m[,c("Order.ID","Warehouse","order.time","deliver.Time")]
  x$deliver.Time <- as.POSIXct(x$deliver.Time , format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')

  x$order.time <- (as.POSIXct(x$order.time, format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'))


  # as.character
  x$diff <- (difftime(x$deliver.Time,x$order.time,units="days"))
  x$TAT <- ifelse(x$diff > 1, paste("Out TAT"), paste("In TAT"))
  x$date <- as.Date(x$deliver.Time)

  table <- dcast(x, Warehouse + date ~  TAT,value.var = "Order.ID", fun.aggregate = length, margins = TRUE)
  table <- table[which(table$date !="(all)"),]


  })

output$view_fwd <-  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({

  view_fwd <- overview()
},class = 'cell-border stripe',options = list(pageLength = 50),
rownames= FALSE))

  })
```

As of now I'm just displaying the 'table' data frame which I got in the server.R, instead of that I want to create a plot or graph which ever may be possible.

Thank you

Comment: I recomment to put all `library()` calls outside the server-function You have them in a `reactive`, so R will try to load/attach those packages everytime the reactive changes, which is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a shiny object, you have to think of two things as a separate: the `ui` object and the `server` object (things get more complicated later but its simpler to start this way)

Whenever you want to show a plot in shiny, first you have to create the plot object using `renderPlot` in the `server` section (this creates the object that will be rendered afterwards) as an **output** object. Second, use a `plotOutput`in the `ui` section for displaying the object in the shiny app.

A short example:

In the `server` section: I chose *any variables x and y* just for making a general idea

```
output$plot <- renderPlot{ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line()}
```

In the `ux` section (inside the section you want to place your plot):
I chose 1400x600 resolution due to personal preference

```
plotOutput("plot", width = "1400px", height = "600px")
```

This should render the plot you want in the place you chose.